# Android intent e-mail not working

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am trying build a simple android app to send an email using android intent property.I used the onClicklistener of a button to trigger the intent function to call e-mail client but it is for some reason not working.All i see when i click the button is the Toast message from the bottom of the code.No prompt asking for e-mail clients or anything.

```
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ( mu.isInternetAvailable(SendMessage.this) ==true)
            {


             Log.i("START ONCLICK","");



              String to = emailid.getText().toString();
              String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
              String driverId1=driverid.getText().toString();
              String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences spmail = SendMessage.this.getSharedPreferences("email", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                driver_mail=spmail.getString("email","");
                Log.i("SEND MAIL id is","DRIVERID "+driver_mail);
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

                //need this to prompts email client only  
                  email.setType("message/rfc822"); 

                  email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                  String[] to1={"info@ZapaTaxi.com"}; 
                  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,  to1);  
                  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);  
                  email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);  



                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :")); 

                  Toast.makeText(SendMessage.this, "E-mail succesfully sent!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Intent it1=new Intent(SendMessage.this,Home.class);
                  startActivity(it1);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the same code, but without any of the parameters, eg the .setData and .putExtra code?

Comment: try this: email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:info@ZapaTaxi.com"));

Comment: I tried both your solutions no change. the problem is no warnings or errors in logcat to identify the issue please help guys.

Comment: Thanks guys issue resolved.it seems we can't write multiple startActivity functions in one method.

Answer (score 0):

you have to place this code somewhere else:

```
 Intent it1=new Intent(SendMessage.this,Home.class);
 startActivity(it1);
```

Comment: no problem, you can accept the answer though (dont know if you can do that either)